# Unable to show Info Window in GoogleMap without clicking on Marker - GoogleMap Cluster Android

Tags: android, google-maps, maps

All, I am using Google Map with [Cluster](https://github.com/pjwelcome/GoogleMapsTutorial). I want to show Info window without clicking on Marker. I added `marker.showInforWindow();` in the `"onClusterItemRendered()"` still info window is not showing automatically. On MapReady am setting renderer to ClusterManager.

```
mClusterManager.setRenderer(new CustomRenderCluster(this, googleMap, mClusterManager));
```

Here am trying to show info window while the Map Marker is rendering

```
@Override
protected void onClusterItemRendered(MyModelItem clusterItem, Marker marker) {
  Log.d("***", "DefaultClusterRenderer - onClusterItemRendered()");
  marker.showInfoWindow();
  super.onClusterItemRendered(clusterItem, marker);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> try putting code after super method like below

```
@Override
protected void onClusterItemRendered(MyModelItem clusterItem, Marker marker) {
  super.onClusterItemRendered(clusterItem, marker); 
 Log.d("***", "DefaultClusterRenderer - onClusterItemRendered()");
  marker.showInfoWindow();

}
```

Comment: No, I tried that also. Still, Info Window is not showing automatically